# boot repair in terminal

Tags: gtk, boot-repair

```
(glade2script:7962): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_cascade_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(glade2script:7962): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(glade2script:7962): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 29:  7962 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $G2S $1 -g ./$PACK_NAME.glade -s ./$APPNAME.sh --combobox="@@_combobox_format_partition@@col" --combobox="@@_combobox_bootflag@@col" --combobox="@@_combobox_ostoboot_bydefault@@col" --combobox="@@_combobox_purge_grub@@col" --combobox="@@_combobox_separateboot@@col" --combobox="@@_combobox_efi@@col" --combobo
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on AskUbuntu. Blame it on me, but I don't understand what you want to ask. You only dumped a few lines of terminal output here and think we can read your mind and examine your computer with a pair of fancy little telepathy antennas? Sorry, but they're broken at the moment ;-) You have to do it the old-school way and write what you want...

Comment: Boot-Repair requires a working gui. You cannot run it from a terminal even though you often start it in the terminal.

Comment: @oldfred That seems to be the answer--I suggest posting it (or something like it) as one.

Answer (score 2):

Boot-Repair uses glade2script and therefore needs some gui. Not sure if just installing glade2script would work or not.
Better to just use the Ubuntu Desktop and add Boot-Repair or download the Boot-RepairCD itself.

It expects to see glade2script.

> Glade2script allows a script (Bash, Python or other) to display and
>   interact with a GUI (created with Glade).